# Google Big Query standard SQL, add a column to a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query from BIg QUERY Google data source and these are actual numbers which auto update every day. I would like to add a column with targeted numbers per day which are static numbers. However i do not know how to input data which are not in the DB. Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros, event.date
FROM `liquidlite-app.com_quoine_quoinex_light_IOS.app_events_20*` AS t
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS ev[![enter image description here][1]][1]ent
WHERE parse_date('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) between
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 40 day) and
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day)

UNION ALL 

SELECT DISTINCT user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros, event.date
FROM `liquidlite-app.com_quoine_quoinex_light_ANDROID.app_events_20*` AS t
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
WHERE parse_date('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) between
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 40 day) and
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day)
```

The query above gives the first 2 columns and I need to add the data in the third column which are not in the DB.
[image: i need this]

Comment: Can you show us sample data?  What does the output look like currently, and how do you want it to look?

Comment: Can you elaborate where the data is coming from? This way we can have a better understanding of the context, specially about this third column

Comment: @Federico Panunzio the first too column are from Google Big Query. The third column is from an excel file.

Comment: Nobody has an idea please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [federated data source](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources) with BigQuery. In this case as you have the data in an excel file, you can move it to Google Sheets and follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive). After you have everything set up it would just to add another `UNION` and query the external data.

Note that there are some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources#external_data_source_limitations) to this, so you’ll have to see if it fits your use case.